# How to parse a RFC date correctly?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

As described in the example table (2nd last entry) on the JavaDoc Page of SimpleDateFormat [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) this should work:

```
    try {
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z")
            .parse("Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But it returns:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
    at de.newsclient.News.main(News.java:42)
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me. However, I suggest you use `dd` for date instead of a simple `d`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_10-b18) Mac OS X 10.8.2.